# Aura Decimal Input value to match number field limit 16,2

Tags: limits, regular-expressions, lightninginput, decimal

I am trying to limit my input number field to exactly match the field values which are 16 digits to 2 decimal digits. Also I want to prevent user from putting something different into the field like a string.

I tried several things but didnt work like max length 18 counts dot as 1 char and allow values like 18 digit with no decimals witch wont be saved due to the limits and will throw an error. I also tried regex but some how couldnt solve the problem.

What should I do? Golden rule is to limit value 'exactly' as the field.

Aura

```
<lightning:input aura:id="Amount" required="true" type="number" name="Amount" step=".01" 
onchange="{!c.validateInput}" value="{!v.newRecord.Amount__c}" label="Amount" />
```

JS

```
validateInput: function(component, event, helper) {
    

    var regex = /^\d{0,16}(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
    var inputElement = event.getSource();
    var inputValue = inputElement.get("v.value");
    if (!regex.test(inputValue)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
            var regtest = regex.test(inputValue[i]);
            console.log(regtest);
            if(!regtest){
                inputValue = inputValue.replace(inputValue[i], "");
                break;
            }
          }
          console.log(inputValue);

          component.set("v.newPaymentInformRecord.Amount__c", inputValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `<lightning:input>`:

- `step="0.01"`
- `max="9999999999999999"` (`maxlength` is just for the length of the string, as you saw, whereas `max` is for numbers)

Comment: Sometimes things do not need to be that complicated. Thx fred.